# bitbucket → 2f9ee0cc7896 [2f9ee0cc7896] meaning

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a set of project managed my git, each project is managed separately. the I put all the project within a folder (I kept the .git directory for each project to keep the local log). then I commited the global directory where all the project are copied. then when I browse online on bitbucket I see this weird naming in my projects sub directories

```
my_project → 2f9ee0cc7896 [2f9ee0cc7896] meaning
```

how can I see my projects

Answer (score 0):

if you have git set-up files or folder in your project it can be seen like that. (I mean the git file must be duplicated)

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more? Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)